# How do I subtract two declared variables in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

The question I am working on is as follows:

What is the difference in the amount received for each month of 2004 compared to 2003?

This is what I have so far,

```
    SELECT @2003 = (SELECT sum(amount) FROM Payments, Orders
                WHERE YEAR(orderDate) = 2003
                AND Payments.customerNumber = Orders.customerNumber
                    GROUP BY MONTH(orderDate));

    SELECT @2004 = (SELECT sum(amount) FROM Payments, Orders
                WHERE YEAR(orderDate) = 2004
                AND Payments.customerNumber = Orders.customerNumber
                    GROUP BY MONTH(orderDate));

    SELECT MONTH(orderDate), (@2004 - @2003) AS Diff 
           FROM Payments, Orders
              WHERE Orders.customerNumber = Payments.customerNumber
                 Group By MONTH(orderDate);
```

In the output I am getting the months but for Diff I am getting NULL please help. Thanks

Comment: Try running each of your initial two queries alone. (from the second select to the semicolon)  Perhaps '@2004' and '@2003' have different values than you expect.

Comment: Just tried that and all the months have different values between the two years.

Comment: So each of these queries produces a list of 12 values?

Comment: Yes, I would show the output but it is on my schools virtual machine and the copy paste is disabled

Comment: '@2003' and '@2004' are both columns with 12 values

Comment: Sorry, I was rash. I deleted my comment.

Comment: That is perfectly OK, thanks for taking a look and trying to help

Comment: Have you tried making the variable names something other than just a number? say orders2006 instead of just '@2006'?

Comment: Still returns null values, I think Bassem is onto something little burned out for the night though 65 queries is a little much so I will return to it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot test this because I don't have your tables, but try something like this:

```
SELECT a.orderMonth, (a.orderTotal - b.orderTotal ) AS Diff 
FROM 
    (SELECT MONTH(orderDate) as orderMonth,sum(amount) as orderTotal 
    FROM Payments, Orders
    WHERE YEAR(orderDate) = 2004
    AND Payments.customerNumber = Orders.customerNumber
        GROUP BY MONTH(orderDate)) as a,
   (SELECT MONTH(orderDate) as orderMonth,sum(amount) as orderTotal FROM Payments, Orders
    WHERE YEAR(orderDate) = 2003
    AND Payments.customerNumber = Orders.customerNumber
        GROUP BY MONTH(orderDate)) as b
WHERE a.orderMonth=b.orderMonth
```

Comment: Trust me you don't want the 4000 lines to create the tables, but that worked. Thanks so much, I should have tried subqueries

Comment: If we received three orders from a customer within a month and one payment, or two payments and no orders, the inline view queries are going to generate a semi-cartesian products. Seems like the question posed was about "amount received".  Are payments received in the same month that an order is placed? In the same year? If this query provides an accurate answer to the question that was asked, it was a horrible question. If it was a good question, then this is a horrible answer.

Comment: It is a basic intro to databases and sql course. The professor(or his lab  assistant?) just made a bunch of questions for us to run queries on so they are all horrible questions. But you are right I needed to change orderDate to paymentDate for a more accurate answer however, he is not looking at the output but the query itself. These are just something for us to grind through for labs and gain sql exp. (BTW we are allowed to have outside help for labs and encouraged to ask questions for self learning)

Answer (score 1):

Q: How do I subtract two declared variables in MySQL.

A: You'd first have to DECLARE them. In the context of a MySQL stored program. But those variable names wouldn't begin with an at sign character. Variable names that start with an at sign **@** character are user-defined variables. And there is no DECLARE statement for them, we can't declare them to be a particular type.

To subtract them within a SQL statement

```
SELECT @foo - @bar AS diff
```

Note that MySQL user-defined variables are *scalar* values.

Assignment of a value to a user-defined variable in a SELECT statement is done with the Pascal style assignment operator  **:=**. In an expression in a SELECT statement, the equals sign is an equality comparison operator.

As a simple example of how to assign a value in a SQL SELECT statement

```
SELECT @foo := '123.45' ;
```

In the OP queries, there's no assignment being done. The equals sign is a comparison, of the scalar value to the return from a subquery.  Are those first statements actually running without throwing an error?

User-defined variables are probably not necessary to solve this problem.

You want to return how many rows? Sounds like you want one for each month. We'll assume that by "year" we're referring to a calendar year, as in January through December. (We might want to check that assumption. Just so we don't find out way too late, that what was meant was the "fiscal year", running from July through June, or something.)

How can we get a list of months? Looks like you've got a start. We can use a GROUP BY or a DISTINCT.

The question was... "What is the difference in the **amount received** ... "

So, we want amount *received*.  Would that be the amount of *payments* we received?  Or the amount of orders that we received? (Are we *taking* orders and *receiving* payments?  Or are we *placing* orders and *making* payments?)

When I think of "amount received", I'm thinking in terms of income.

Given the only two tables that we see, I'm thinking we're *filling* orders and *receiving* payments. (I probably want to check that, so when I'm done, I'm not told... "oh, we meant the number of orders we received" and/or "the payments table is the payments we made, the 'amount we received' is in some other table"

We're going to assume that there's a column that identifies the "date" that a payment was received, and that the datatype of that column is DATE (or DATETIME or TIMESTAMP), some type that we can reliably determine what "month" a payment was received in.

To get a list of months that we received payments in, in 2003...

```
 SELECT MONTH(p.payment_received_date)
   FROM payment_received p
  WHERE p.payment_received_date >= '2003-01-01'
    AND p.payment_received_date <  '2004-01-01'
  GROUP BY MONTH(p.payment_received_date)
  ORDER BY MONTH(p.payment_received_date)
```

That should get us twelve rows. Unless we didn't receive any payments in a given month. Then we might only get 11 rows. Or 10. Or, if we didn't receive any  payments in all of 2003, we won't get any rows back.

For performance, we want to have our predicates (conditions in the WHERE clause0 reference bare columns. With an appropriate index available, MySQL will make effective use of an index range scan operation. If we wrap the columns in a function, e.g.

```
  WHERE YEAR(p.payment_received_date) = 2003
```

With that, we will be forcing MySQL to evaluate that function on *every* flipping row in the table, and then compare the return from the function to the literal. We prefer not do do that, and reference bare columns in predicates (conditions in the WHERE clause).

We could repeat the same query to get the payments received in 2004. All we need to do is change the date literals.

Or, we could get all the rows in 2003 and 2004 all together, and collapse that into a list of distinct months.

We can use conditional aggregation. Since we're using calendar years, I'll use the YEAR() shortcut (rather than a range check). Here, we're not as concerned with using a bare column inside the expression.

```
SELECT MONTH(p.payment_received_date) AS `mm`
     , MAX(MONTHNAME(p.payment_received_date)) AS `month`
     , SUM(IF(YEAR(p.payment_received_date)=2004,p.payment_amount,0)) AS `2004_month_total`
     , SUM(IF(YEAR(p.payment_received_date)=2003,p.payment_amount,0)) AS `2003_month_total`
     , SUM(IF(YEAR(p.payment_received_date)=2004,p.payment_amount,0))
     - SUM(IF(YEAR(p.payment_received_date)=2003,p.payment_amount,0)) AS `2004_2003_diff`
  FROM payment_received p
 WHERE p.payment_received_date >= '2003-01-01'
   AND p.payment_received_date <  '2005-01-01'
 GROUP
    BY MONTH(p.payment_received_date)
 ORDER
    BY MONTH(p.payment_received_date)
```

---

If this is a homework problem, I strongly recommend you work on this problem yourself. There are other query patterns that will return an equivalent result.

Comment: Thanks, you put a lot of time into this answer and I learned a lot from it

Comment: The only way that the query with the semi-join of the payments table and the orders table is coming up with a "correct" answer is if customerNumber is guaranteed to be *unique* in either orders or payments.

Comment: The customerNumber auto increments and is the Primary Key of the table Customers and a foreign Key in both the Payments and Orders Table

Comment: Consider what happens when a customer places two orders in January 2003,  and made a total of five payments in all of 2003, another four payments in 2004, and another three payments in 2005. The join predicates (in the selected answer) says that each of the orders in January will match each of the thirteen payments. That's going to be total of 2x13 rows... 2 copies of each of the payments, all of those  payments counted in January. No flipping way that is the result the question is asking for. It doesn't matter when the order was placed. The question is asking when payment was received.

Comment: Again in my comment to you in the above answer I said I made a mistake and orderDate should be paymentDate so yes you are correct. All of the info I needed was in one table.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem:
In @2003 and @2004, you select only the sum. And even if you group by the month you still select one column i.e. each row does not say what month it is select for. So when you try to subtract SQL asks which row in @2003 should be subtracted from @2004.
So I think the solution is to select the month with the sum and do the subtract later based on the month.